# Things turn out to be very different in the job compared to what it's mentioned in the offer letter

Tags: job-description

I am working in the IT department of a retail company. I was offered position X, reporting to Mr. A. There was another position vacant/open, Y.

When I joined the company, my reporting got changed. I was asked to report to B who reports to A. Also, as the position Y was open, I primarily worked in position Y (80% or more on position Y) and maybe less than 20% in position X (which I was originally hired for).

I could do both X and Y, but X definitely pays more than Y as skill set, for X is more in demand. I migrated (upgraded from Y to X) almost 6 years back...
Surprisingly, Mr. A's favorite employee who was comfortable with X position keeps on working in position X as a primary person.

When I started objecting about it (in a respectful, amicable and professional manner), I faced great reaction and retaliation. Now Mr. A as well as Mr. B are both against me. Also the person who was working on my position is also not happy with me. They all ganged up and as I am new to this place, I am facing all sort of issues. What to do?

I am reporting one level down as well kept away from my original position for several months. I have been threatened with a bad performance review because I even resisted this practice here.

It seems the offer letter has no value here. When I reported this matter to HR (HR is always the manager's friend and the manager is always right, this is the case here in this company), HR is simply telling me that even if you worked for position Y instead of X, you were paid during that time.

Comment: Polish your CV...

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [How do I decline responsibilities that go beyond what's stated in my job description?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/21793)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti. Sure will do but what about resisting and get it fixed?

Comment: I'm assuming you're getting the pay for the position you signed for, despite working on something else?

Comment: @ashu If you like the _new_ job and it's not detrimental for your career then definitely "why not?". Of course if it's just temporary then you don't even have the problem.

Comment: @Erik - good point. Same point HR also made. But I am hired for position X and working for position Y. Position X is having more market rate than position Y. I am loosing my market value if i continue working on position X. And that's not the only issue - at the time of appraisal - what i will be evaluated for?

Answer (score 6):

> When i started objecting about it(in a respectful, amicable and professional) manner - I faced great reaction and retaliation. Now Mr. A as well as Mr. B are both against me. Also the person who was working on my position - that person is also not happy with me. They all ganged up and as I am new to this place - I am facing all sort of issues.

If you are being ganged up upon by your bosses, and HR is doing nothing to solve the issue, I would be sending out applications to other jobs right away.  This sounds like a toxic work environment and it will only get worse if you stay.