# Working outside your job descirption

Tags: job-description

I was hired to be a secretary 3 years ago however, I possess Financial experience.  Even though I was hired as an Secretary, I was brought in and was set up to do financial tasks with half of an alphabet population of patients where I secure authorizations for evaluations, listings, Inpatient transplant surgeries as well as post transplant care.  I must manage every patient's insurance issues, advise them if they need to change insurance, maintain active authorizations for all of the existing as well as new patient's. etc.

I also travel (Some overnight and as much as two days) to do the financial registration for all of the patient's in the outlining locations to ensure they have coverage for the services.  I was hosting a departmental huddle meeting every Friday.  I have to give the approval for a patient to be listed for an organ and nothing happens until I give the approval.  I have asked to be promoted to the Financial coordinator position (As this is the job, I actually perform)  I have been told there wasn't any open positions which I understand.

Well a position became available and I wasn't informed however, once I found out I asked my supervisor about the position.  She then asked if I thought I was a team player.  I was astounded.  I said yes, I do.  Anything that needs to be done I do it without complaint.  I come in early when needed.  I cover other areas when needed. and in the 3 years I have been here I have never had any issues.  Never been written up or reprimanded.  I present to work on time and do my job. Then I was told that I act like I don't want to talk to anyone sometimes.  I come in and speak and proceed to sit down and work.  I engage in little conversation but, will talk when being talked to.

After that, I was told that she felt I needed more training.  I again, was astounded.  I have done the job for 3 years and continue to do this everyday without supervision and none of these "concerns" have been addressed in my evaluations or ever made a discussion.  It became clear that I was not going to be considered for the job.  I asked that I be considered for the job or, sent down to the area where the rest of the secretaries are to do what I was hired to do.   I expressed that I do a financial coordinators job everyday (for 3 years) yet, I am paid a secretary's salary.

I feel it is appropriate to either allow me to be sent down where I am suppose to be and be a secretary or, to be considered for the position that I currently do.  I also feel that they should retro-actively pay me for the wages they have shorted me for 3 years and counting.  I am still doing the finance job and receiving the wage set for a secretary.  What is my recourse?

Comment: Walls of text hurt my eyes, but, based on the title, is this a duplicate of [My job responsibility is more than is noted in job description. How do I decline these additional responsibilities?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21793/my-job-responsibility-is-more-than-is-noted-in-job-description-how-do-i-decline) or [How to politely turn down a task that is beyond the scope of my job description?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15120/how-to-politely-turn-down-a-task-that-is-beyond-the-scope-of-my-job-description)

Comment: Well, you're not getting retrospective pay unless you're in some insanely highly influential union - either way, I think that's a hiding to nothing. What you should probably do is update your CV with your new experience, fluff your job title a little if you can without lying, and seek other employment.

Answer (score 3):

> I asked that I be considered for the job or, sent down to the area
>   where the rest of the secretaries are to do what I was hired to do. I
>   expressed that I do a financial coordinators job everyday (for 3
>   years) yet, I am paid a secretary's salary. I feel it is appropriate
>   to either allow me to be sent down where I am suppose to be and be a
>   secretary or, to be considered for the position that I currently do.

But you already indicate that they don't intend to do that.

> I also feel that they should retro-actively pay me for the wages they
>   have shorted me for 3 years and counting.

Clearly that isn't going to happen.

If you didn't want to perform the non-secretarial duties without additional compensation, the time to deal with that was when they were first assigned, not 3 years later.

> I am still doing the finance job and receiving the wage set for a
>   secretary. What is my recourse?

You probably already know that you should find a new job, get and accept an offer, then turn in your notice here.

If for some reason you don't want to leave, you could ask for a title change and a raise while keeping your existing duties. But you may already have burned that bridge.

Comment: No need for me to answer, now.  +1.  Sucks for OP, but there doesn't seem to be a lot of options there.

Answer (score 0):

> I also feel that they should retro-actively pay me for the wages they have shorted me for 3 years and counting

There will never be any shortage of people who have contributed to others' efforts without any prior agreement for compensation who end up feeling used and abused.  You've done this for three years, and I must say from the beginning that overall this is no one's doing but your *own*.

People don't appreciate what you give away for free.  What's worse: in your situation, when you decided to gather the courage to ask for what you're worth, you got fed a "line" by your supervisor to basically put you back in your low place on the totem pole.  But let's trace back to whenever you started doing these tasks outside of the 'secretary' responsibilities.  How did it come about?

I'm going to take a guess that maybe you spotted something awry in a report, or overheard a conversation about a lapse, and decided to get yourself involved and fix the issue.  Or maybe you were initially recognized at some point by a supervisor for being a problem-solver in a pinch.  In either case, the end result was an ego stroke.  And the people over you figured that **because you never raised a need beyond an ego stroke**, you were happy just receiving a "good job" and a pat on the back.  Now, three years in, you're demanding change -- but they've gotten used to you accepting the pat on the back, so you're getting push-back.

The good news is that you seem to be a valuable asset to a team.  The bad news is that you're going to have to find another team, on another job; when you do, don't miss any opportunity to speak up for yourself, or you're going to find yourself in the same boat again.   There's some program in your head that says that it's selfish or improper to ask for help with your needs until you're at a desperate point.  I really hope you can find this thing, and choke the living sh-- out of it.  You seem like a great person, and to reach this goal you're going to have to start putting yourself first much sooner.

Best of luck.