# Should a Chief Technology Officer be making a Business Document or a Requirement Document?

Tags: tech-industry, technology, business

I am the CTO at a mid sized startup. Still a guy in my late 20s exploring this new role that I have gotten upon my shoulders.

Currently we don't have a tech team, I handle the work outsourced to the tech services company. I also handle the future plans and scopes of the company technology wise. This is until we get the complete handover from the tech service company, so that all tech can be handled in-house from then on.

The hierarchy is a bit confused here and one of the business development person just asked me to write a requirement document for a feature to be shared with the company we are outsourcing the tech to saying "You know it better". I am not sure if this is something in my Job description and if I should be allowing anyone to assign me.

I am here to do tech. I am unaware if CTOs should be writing business documents as well. Please help.

Comment: How big (many employees) is your startup? What industry? - I'm guessing not a tech startup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to politely turn down a task that is beyond the scope of my job description?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15120/how-to-politely-turn-down-a-task-that-is-beyond-the-scope-of-my-job-description)

Comment: How can you be a CTO and not know how to write a requirements doc or manage vendors?

Comment: Well, if you didn't do it, who would? Is there anyone else that can? Work doesn't confine itself to job descriptions, so if there is work that needs to be done, who will do it?

Answer (score 25):

You are in a start up.  **Yes**, those two things are reasonable to ask of a C level executive.

In fact, I expect that you will *need to wear many hats* including the two you mentioned in your question.  This is the **pain** of a *start up*, you are going to get a lot of tasks thrown at you, and some of them may not be within what you perceive as the boundaries.

Once your company grows, I would expect some of the *border line* items to fall off, but until then you are the guy from anything *resembling* a technical perspective.

Comment: Mr P, that's almost exactly what I was going to write. I was still mulling over exactly how big a "mid size" startup is, and why it would outsource all tech, unless its a non-tech startup of course.

Comment: I agreee! And I just want to add one thing - as a CTO you should also be willing to take upon the work, and set an example for other people in the company that "you do what you have to do in order for the company to succeed." You can't in all honesty expect others to go above and beyond when you aren't willing to open Word and write a document...Grow up, do your job and keep the team moving.

Comment: ^ that comment should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This answer is very good.  The CTO must be willing to do any job that is within their skillset, if it writing a requirement document for a project within their department, and there isn't enough else it can be assigned to then they must be the one to complete it.  If for some reason the CTO cannot write the document, then they should hire somebody who they can directly interface with, who can write the document for them (i.e. a Deputy CTO).

Answer (score 20):

> I am not sure if this is something in my Job description and if I
>   should be allowing anyone to assign me.
>
> I am here to do tech. I am unaware if CTOs should be writing business
>   documents as well. Please help.

A C-level executive is there to do whatever it takes, not just to "do tech".

You and the other C-levels need to get together and decide how to get things done, and who is in the best position to do them.

A Job Description is just a piece of paper. In a startup, things need to get done.

Answer (score 1):

There are no silos in an early stage start up, within reason you have to take on a lot of roles, including some non-technical ones. Mind you, CTO in late 20's is pretty cool so learn as much as you can and use the experience to build out your broader skills. Just make sure the senior team are sharing that workload and you're not taking on more than your fair share.

Answer (score 0):

As a **CTO**, you will only care about the **strategies** of your area (technical).

However, since the company is small and there are no suitable employees available, you will need to cover more roles:

- **project manager**: you will deal with the **QCT** of the project;
- **business analyst**: you will write **requirements**;
- others...

Although you will do everything, do not randomly assign work products to roles. I.e., do not assume that you write requirements as a CTO.

This way of thinking will help you big time when the company will grow and you will be able to hand over the extra-roles. You will know exactly what to give to who.