# How to let my boss know that monitoring business performance is not my duty?

Tags: management, work-environment, projects

My boss has been asking me to monitor the business performance for the whole company. However, we have a business operating manager who is supposed to do this task. I have explained this to my boss several times, but she just ignored all my suggestions on how to solve this problem. Would anyone give me some suggestions on how to convince her stop requesting me to duplicate the workload?

Background: I am working as an assistant marketing manager of a company. We are only a small team, and we provide supportive services such as design and production, communication, website, facebook, youtube, reporting, advertisement and PR, to the whole company.  We don't have the skill sets to collect data and do the analysis work. And, of course, we are not the proper role to do business performance analysis, given that there are other resources on hand who officially have this as part of their role.

I suggested let our business analyst to prepare a monthly report to her. However, she kept asking us to do by ourselves. What my boss requested not only overloading the whole team, but also make us very frustrated as we explained so many times.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you contacted the person in charge of monitoring the business performance of the whole company? or forwarded them the requests from your Manager?Also I'm not sure if your boss wants to you to just read the report, summarize the report, hand her the report or generate a new report. Can you please clarify exactly what it is your boss wants you to do when she says "monitor the business performance of the whole company"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to politely turn down a task that is beyond the scope of my job description?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15120/how-to-politely-turn-down-a-task-that-is-beyond-the-scope-of-my-job-description)

Comment: What my boss requested me is do the whole thing: gather the data, prepare the report, summarize, discuss with difference department heads find out the meaning of the numbers and give her conclusion and suggestions (not only Marketing, but also in the operation and business points of views).

Comment: I tried to turn down this job politely, explained that's not my skill set to do such kind of things, and proposed solution to fullfill her requirement and even arrange the meeting with her and the business analyst (who was assigned to monitor and analysis the business on a monthly basis with the Business Operation Manager). She agreed to let the business analyst to prepare the report and analysis for her, but she still requested me to prepare for her, before she met the business analysis.

Comment: If your boss doesn't understand this simple fact, then it's likely she doesn't understand some other, more complicated, ones either. Perhaps it's time to start looking for a new job.

Comment: *She agreed to let the business analyst to prepare the report and analysis for her, but she still requested me to prepare for her, before she met the business analysis* - so, she has agreed to let the other person do the report? But she just wants you to "prepare" it before she meets with the other person? It sounds like your boss thinks you can add value by "preparing" the report. Has she seen what the other person can produce? Is there some marketing department specific version she wants you to work on, based on that person's work?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and advise. Very useful to me. After 3 months later, I found out she did not want to listen to or discuss with the business analysis. More accurate, she wanted to have the report with analysis earlier than all the other department heads and senior administrators... office political issue.

Answer (score 5):

> "However, we have business operating manager to do this task"

So the question is does your boss just want the task done, and is delegating the management of it to you, or do they specifically want *you* to do the work, not the business operating manager?

It could be they want the report done and checked on a regular basis for them to review, or they don't like, or don't trust, the business operating managers work and so specifically want you to do it.

You say you are an assistant marketing manager, so presumably your boss is the/a marketing manager. It sounds like they are delegating the task and it's your responsibility to get it done (even if that 'just' means chasing up the business operating manager), but I'd check with your boss that this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common phenomenon that happens in larger companies. They start to hire many people and several roles eventually start to overlap or become blurry as to whose responsibility the reporting lies with. eventually you end up with enough people to push every button in the place four times over but ironically leadership thinks everyone is essential to the cause.

If your boss keeps nagging you to do this report even though it's going to duplicate things just take solace in knowing you get paid either way. it is disheartening knowing that they don't value your time and expertise a little more but at the very least you can probably create some sort of template and automate most of it away.